# Couldn't install scikit

Tags: scikit-learn, anaconda, installation, scikits

While installing `scikit learn` this is what I get in terminal:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'd:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\dfitpack.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

How do I find the main user folder?

I've tried this code:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn scipy matplotlib
```

Comment: Please include the output of `conda info` in your question.

Comment: You broke your Anaconda installation by using `pip` to install the packages you mentioned above. Now you need to uninstall Anaconda and reinstall it again. In the future please use `conda` instead of `pip` to install those packages (that's because `conda` and `pip` packages are binary incompatible).

Answer (score 0):

Try to install packages using anaconda navigator. Launch the app then go to environments and select the packages that you want to install and then click apply.

Comment: Preferably, create a new conda environment rather than trying to add things to the base env.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a problem to install libs with pip as long as your conda config has pip installed.

To your problem:

either do `sudo pip install -U scikit-learn scipy matplotlib`

or as state `pip install -U scikit-learn scipy matplotlib --user`

Your problem is with the permissions because you probably do not have an vena active.